# Difficulty assembling maven plugin with Eclipse IDE for android

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I am trying to assemble Maven plug-in with Eclipse IDE. I want to make an android application.

I have installed android-release archtype, and have made a new Maven project. When I make a new project, three files - projectname, projectname-it and projectname-parent are formed.

But it shows error :

```
GroupId is duplicate of parent groupId
VersionId is duplicate of parent versionId
```

in pom.xml of projectname and projectname-it file and

error :

```
     Multiple markers at this line
    - Line breakpoint:HelloAndroidActivity [line: 21] - 
     onCreate(Bundle)
    - R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

in HelloAndroidActivity.java file of projectname.

What should I do ?

Comment: The errors are not linked : duplicated GroupId is just an Eclipse warning (you have got an option in your preferences to remove this warning). R is auto-generated with Android. Check if it is really generated in your target folder and check your path too. Check on Stackoverflow for this error : there are already plenty of answers

Comment: @willome No, I checked it. It is not auto generated.